# Itextsharp gradient background

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

Is there way to set gradient background to pdfcell or paragraph? Or do I have to use image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, iText and iTextSharp support gradient colors. The `PdfShading` object has several static methods that create different types of `PdfShading` objects for you. The two that you are probably most interested in are `SimpleAxial` and `SimpleRadial`. There's three others named `Type1`, `Type2` and `Type3` that I haven't explored yet.

Once you have a `PdfShading` object you can create a `PdfShadingPattern` directly from it and once you have that you can create a `ShadingColor` from it. `ShadingColor` is ultimately derived from `BaseColor` so you should be able to use it wherever that's used. In your case you want to assign it to a `BackgroundColor`.

Below is a complete working WinForms app targeting iTextSharp 5.1.1.0 that shows created a table with two columns, each with their own gradient background colors.

**NOTE**: The (x,y) coordinates of the `PdfShading` static methods are document-level and not cell-level. What this means is that you might not be able to re-use `PdfShading` ojbects depending on the gradient's size. After this sample below I'll show you how to overcome this limitation using cell events.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Test file name
            string TestFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Test.pdf");

            //Standard iTextSharp setup
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(TestFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER))
                {
                    using (PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                    {
                        //Open the document for writing
                        doc.Open();

                        //Create a shading object. The (x,y)'s appear to be document-level instead of cell-level so they need to be played with
                        PdfShading shading = PdfShading.SimpleAxial(w, 0, 700, 300, 700, BaseColor.BLUE, BaseColor.RED);

                        //Create a pattern from our shading object
                        PdfShadingPattern pattern = new PdfShadingPattern(shading);

                        //Create a color from our patter
                        ShadingColor color = new ShadingColor(pattern);

                        //Create a standard two column table
                        PdfPTable t = new PdfPTable(2);

                        //Add a text cell setting the background color through object initialization
                        t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Hello")) { BackgroundColor = color });

                        //Add another cell with everything inline. Notice that the (x,y)'s have been updated
                        t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("World")) { BackgroundColor = new ShadingColor(new PdfShadingPattern(PdfShading.SimpleAxial(w, 400, 700, 600, 700, BaseColor.PINK, BaseColor.CYAN))) });



                        //Add the table to the document
                        doc.Add(t);

                        //Close the document
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            this.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

**Example 2**

As noted above, the method above uses document-level position which often isn't good enough. To overcome this you need to use cell-level positioning and to do that you need to use cell events because cell positions aren't known until the table itself is rendered. To use a cell event you need to create a new class that implements `IPdfPCellEvent` and handle the `CellLayout` method. Below is updated code that does all of this:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Test file name
            string TestFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Test.pdf");

            //Standard iTextSharp setup
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(TestFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER))
                {
                    using (PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                    {
                        //Open the document for writing
                        doc.Open();

                        //Create a standard two column table
                        PdfPTable t = new PdfPTable(2);

                        //Create an instance of our custom cell event class, passing in our main writer which is needed by the PdfShading object
                        var CE = new GradientBackgroundEvent(w);

                        //Set the default cell's event to our handler
                        t.DefaultCell.CellEvent = CE;

                        //Add cells normally
                        t.AddCell("Hello");
                        t.AddCell("World");


                        //Add the table to the document
                        doc.Add(t);

                        //Close the document
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            this.Close();
        }

        public class GradientBackgroundEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
        {
            //Holds pointer to main PdfWriter object
            private PdfWriter w;

            //Constructor
            public GradientBackgroundEvent(PdfWriter w)
            {
                this.w = w;
            }

            public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
            {
                //Create a shading object with cell-specific coords
                PdfShading shading = PdfShading.SimpleAxial(w, position.Left, position.Bottom, position.Right, position.Top, BaseColor.BLUE, BaseColor.RED);

                //Create a pattern from our shading object
                PdfShadingPattern pattern = new PdfShadingPattern(shading);

                //Create a color from our patter
                ShadingColor color = new ShadingColor(pattern);

                //Get the background canvas. NOTE, If using an older version of iTextSharp (4.x) you might need to get the canvas in a different way
                PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];

                //Set the background color of the given rectable to our shading pattern
                position.BackgroundColor = color;

                //Fill the rectangle
                cb.Rectangle(position);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer.  Fricking itext documentation should read like this.

Comment: @ChirsHaas any chance you could help me fill a circle with a radial gradient starting in the centre? pretty please

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else is still interested 
I was looking to find out how to color the whole background with a gradient
you can do it like this....

```
    PdfShading shading = PdfShading.simpleAxial(writer, 0, pageH, pageW, 0,
            BaseColor.WHITE, BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
    PdfShadingPattern pattern = new PdfShadingPattern(shading);
    cb.setShadingFill(pattern);
    // cb.circle(500, 500, 500);
    cb.rectangle(0, 0, pageW, pageH);
    cb.fill();
```